# White background displayed before rendering paper-menu-button items

Tags: polymer

When clicking on the toolbar's buttons, I can see a white background displayed before rendering the menu in green. See the [demo](http://jsbin.com/hagegi/1/).

Appreciate if someone can let me know what I did wrong as I am new to Polymer.

Update: Including demo code based on inputs (removed unrelated code) and solution provided by Dirk. The code below will display menu with appropriate background color DURING animation rendering (green in this case).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <script rel="import" src="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-icons/core-icons.html">

    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-menu-button/paper-menu-button.html">
</head>
<body unresolved fullbleed layout>
    <my-app></my-app>
    <polymer-element name="my-app" noscript>
        <template>
            <style>
                :host {
                    display: block;
                    height: 100%;
                    background-color: #0000ff;
                }

                paper-item {
                    font-size: 0.5em;
                    color: white;
                    /* --- remove this */
                    /*background-color: green;*/
                }

                /* --- add this */
                paper-menu-button /deep/ .paper-menu-button-overlay-bg {
                    background: green;
                }
            </style>
                <paper-menu-button icon="menu">
                    <paper-item icon="settings" label="Settings"></paper-item>
                    <paper-item icon="add" label="Add"></paper-item>
                    <paper-item icon="search" label="Search"></paper-item>
                </paper-menu-button>
        </template>
    </polymer-element>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the relevant parts of your code in your question for future reference. It is easier to get an overview of a question if everything is in one place and the JS Bin could be deleted in the future.

Then remove the `background: green` entry from the `paper-item` section. It is not needed since we style the background color of the popup menu elsewhere (another problem with this styling is, that it removes the round corners form the popup menu. This may or may not be intentional.)

Eventually add

```
paper-menu-button /deep/ .paper-menu-button-overlay-bg {
  background: green;
}
```

to your styles and now everything looks much nicer. This section styles the background of the *paper-menu-button* popup, aka *overlay*.

Is this the proper way to do it? I don't know. Because now you have a dependency on the internals of the *paper-menu-button* in your CSS. I think in the future all *core* and *paper* elements need (to some extend) be completely themeable, meaning you can specify most of the core colors and styles for all components in a single place.